# Changing the ActionBar title wiith change in the current fragment

Tags: android

I have an Activity which has a
`android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`, which in turn has a `FrameLayout` and `A Side Menu Fragment`.
The side menu has 3 options.
Each option will dynamically add a new fragment to the `FrameLayout` and any action done on the Fragment will keep adding few more fragment.

**Eg:**
If I select option-1 it is a 5 step process. Lets say a Quiz.
You submit 1st answer, 2nd fragment with a new question comes up(while the previous question being in the back stack) and so on. Finally ending at question 5.
Option-2 has a similar kind of process with 3 stages and so does Option-3.

My requirement is to Put the Actionbar title as "Option-1" whenever there is a fragment of that sequence visible to the user.

**What I tried:**

I made a super fragment which every other fragment extends and this super fragment has a fields **title**, which I set when I am adding it to the FrameLayout.
And **onBackStackChanged** I would get the top most fragment using the entry count and get the title from it and set as the Action bar title.

```
fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new 

    FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            Fragment visibleFragment = fragmentManager.getFragments().get(count > 0 ? count - 1 : count);
            Log.d("onBackStackChanged", "" + visibleFragment);
            //actionBar.setTitle(visibleFragment.title);
        }
    });
```

But the problem here is, when I see the logs, it is not the visible fragment that comes in the `visibleFragment` field, it is something random. I mean sometimes even I get SideMenuFragment there which is actually static in the xml

Is there an easy and better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an interface as @Jibbo suggested ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)), that is the right way Fragments and Activities should communicate (what @Hiren Patel said, is not the way, because Fragments aren't reusable with other Activities - he used a public method in the activity).

Your comment: How to handle the back pressed and title you could override the onBackPressed method in your **MainActivity** and check the fragment TAG, to determine on which Fragment we pressed back, and than set the title according to this.

You set the TAG when starting the Fragment

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
     .beginTransaction()
     .add(R.id.content_frame, new QuizFragment(), FRAGMENT_TAG_QUIZ)
     .addToBackStack(FRAGMENT_TAG_QUIZ)
     .commit();
```

Detect back pressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // Check fragment back stack so we can set the right action bar title
    int fragmentCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (fragmentCount != 0)
    {
        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentCount - 1);
        String fragmentTag = backEntry.getName();

        if (fragmentTag != null)
        {
            // If back pressed when on Quiz
            switch (fragmentTag) {
                case FRAGMENT_TAG_QUIZ:
                   setActionBarTitle("Quiz");
                   break;
                ....
            }
        }
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: The problem is here: `FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentCount - 1);` This is something similar to what I do currently. But instead of `fragmentManager.getFragments().get(count > 0 ? count - 1 : count)` You are using the `getBackStackEntryAt` My question is will this for sure give the backstack tag of the fragment which is on top i.e currently visible to the user? Unlike the fragment which is random when I use `fragmentManager.getFragments()`

Comment: This will for sure give you the visible fragment, because it takes the last fragment added to backstack (**getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentCount - 1)**). I had a similar problem to yours and this is how I solved it.

Comment: Okay. I will try this out.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in the following way:

I'll create an interface like:

```
public interface ChangeTitleListener{
    public void setTitle(String title);
}
```

And I'll make the activity implement it.
Then, In the fragments:

```
private ChangeListener mListener;

@Override
public void OnAttach(Activity activity){
    if(activity instanceof ChangeTitleListener){
        mListener = (ChangeListener) activity;
    }
    else{
        throw new RuntimeException("The activity must implement ChangeListener");
    }
}
```

Now you can call `mListener.setTitle(SOMETHING);` when you need. I'll suggest calling it in the `onResume()` method since it's not an expensive action and you need it every time a fragment is displayed.

Comment: *onResume()* will not get called when returning to the fragment with pressing back on another fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way:

In your **Activity**:

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

Set Actionbar **title** from **Fragment**:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Set title bar
    ((MainFragmentActivity) getActivity())
            .setActionBarTitle("Your title");

}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: But this does not work with Back Stack. When I have a Fragment of Option-1 the title would be "Option-1", when I add a new Fragment of Option-2 on top the title would be "Option-2", but the problem is when I press back button and come back to the Fragment of Option-1, the title would still remain as "Option-2" right?

Comment: put code on onCreate() of fragment: setHasOptionMenu(true); & invalidateOptionMenu();